# Add a MSI file to new Installshield project

Tags: installation, installshield

I want to create a new InstallShield project which has two prerequisites. I need this new InstallShield project to include an `msi` file. How can I add an `msi` file to a new Installshield project?

I heard about the chained msi but doing this I can not add pre-requisites.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're using a Basic MSI project in the Professional or Premier edition of InstallShield. If so, you can use the Prerequisite Editor from the Tools menu to create a .prq file that detects and installs the required .msi file. Then add that .prq file into your main project, for a total of 3 prerequisites.